# I can't run this program in Eclipse

Tags: java

I can't run this program in Eclipse. Eclipse doesn't say anything's wrong, I just couldn't open it. Every time I try, it will open another program in my default package instead.

```
import acm.util.*;

/**
 * This class decides the face of a coin. 
 * 1 and 2 represent correspondingly Heads and Tails.
 * Clients can get the "face" of the coin by calling getState() method.
 */

public class CoinFace {

    public CoinFace() {
        state = rgen.nextInt(1, 2);
    }

    private int state;

    public int getState() {
        return state;
    }

    private RandomGenerator rgen = new RandomGenerator();
}

public class ConsecutiveHeads extends CoinFace{
    public void run () {
        while (true) {
            int totalFlip = 0;
            int consecutiveHeads = 0;
            CoinFace a = new CoinFace();
            if (a.getState() == 1) {
                System.out.print("Heads");
                totalFlip++;
                consecutiveHeads++;
            } else if (consecutiveHeads == 3) {
                System.out.print("It took " + totalFlip + " to get 3 consecutive heads." );
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.print("Tails");
                consecutiveHeads = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what happens when you try? What is CoinFace? Where is your `main` method? You haven't given us enough information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: I can't see a main method here

Comment: I really hope you have `main` somewhere there..

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun, he hopes, too :D

Comment: -1 for blaming Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot declaring a main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  new ConsecutiveHeads().run(); 
}
```